# Trunk release switch & connector

Tags: pontiac, connector, g6, switches, trunk

Im trying to figure out what you would call the connector for the trunk release button on a 2010 Pontiac G6. The actual button has 4 pins & the plug/connector only shows 3 metal contacts. There is power coming from the 3 holes so I'm trying to figure out if there should be 4 and if so what is the name of the parrot that I would need to replace.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *exactly* sure which you are talking about, so will give you a couple different options and let you decide ...

The switch in the dash is called the [**trunk lid release switch**](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/pontiac,2010,g6,3.5l+v6,1446299,electrical-switch+&+relay,trunk+lid+release+switch,4828) and is ACDelco PN D1409G. The OEM PN on this is 15853223.

If you are talking about the mechanism in the trunk which unlatches the lid, it's called a [**trunk lock actuator**](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/pontiac,2010,g6,3.5l+v6,1446299,body,trunk+lock+actuator,13397) and can be replaced with Doorman PN 940109. I didn't see an OEM PN associated with this piece.

Answer (score 0):

On the switch, only the a, c & d terminals are used. A is chassis ground, c is the signal to the bcm and d is illumination.

If you have power on the a terminal when back probing than the ground circuit is open.

Either add a new ground or trace the wiring to find the open.